# Using Java RegEx, how do I compare a variable with another variable, while ignoring quotes and white space?

Tags: java, regex

I have two variables. Variable 1 is in the format

```
"          35"
```

while variable 2 is just

```
35
```

How would I compare these two?

Comment: How about `"          35".trim().equals("35".trim())` ?

Comment: @MElliott The problem with that is that I have a bunch of variables that I wanted to compare in a loop so I needed a way to test generic variables. Some of them had spaces and quotes, others didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
var1.replaceAll("\\W+", "").equals( var2.replaceAll("\\W+", "") )
```

Here `replaceAll("\\W+", "")` will remove all non-word characters from both variables before comparing.